# Access Outer Class this instance

Tags: java, oop

how do we access outer class this instance: eg in

```
Class A {

   Class B {

      this.helloB();
      (A's this).hello()
   }
}
```

how do we access A's this instance in Java

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just call

```
A.this.hello()
```

Answer (score 16):

By prefixing `this` with the class: `A.this.hello()`

Similarly, when you want to create an instance of B outside of A, you can use `a.new B()` (where `a instanceof A == true`).