# How to refer to Enclosing class from Inner class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, nested, synchronized

I am extending ArrayList to create a custom ArrayList that can be modified using normal ArrayList methods while iterating over it. For this I am also creating an Iterator.

```
public class SynchronizedList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{
    // Fields here

    //Constructors and methods here

public class SynchronizedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>
{
    public int index;
    private E current;

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        synchronized (/* reference to enclosing List object */) {
                    //code goes here
        }
        return false;
    }

    //more methods here
}
}
```

During my hasNext() and next() methods, I need to make sure the list is not modified (it can be modified at any other time). Hence I need to refer to my enclosing type in my synchronized() block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Outer Class this instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721608/access-outer-class-this-instance) and [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EnclosingType.this`. So in your case, it would be `SynchronizedList.this`.